# How to change icon of: taskbar, in the top left corner, icon when Alt-Tab is pressed, of my .exe

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013, windows-7

Platform: Windows 7

IDE: VS2013

Language: C++

Windows class: WinAPI

I have a custom image: Icon.png.

I also have a windows class from the msdn sample code to create a basic Win32 window.
It has two things hIcon and hIconSm of my windows class structure which I am not sure what they correspond to, but they both are probably related to icons.

I need to: Change the icon of the taskbar to Icon.png, do same thing for the icons in top left corner of the exe, and change the icon which displays when alt+tab is pressed.

So that means I need to know which variables I change, what functions to use, and what its parameters stand for. Also if any clicking in VS or additional file creation is needed I also need instructions on how to do that.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS I tried the stuff posted by other people on here but it either didn't work or the instructions were unclear, hence my asking for specifics.

Comment: Why do you think this is even possible? Where are you going to get a hook on the task switcher? Do you have evidence that this can be done?

Comment: Actually I'm confused by what you are asking. Do you want to change the window icon while the program is running, in response to a task switch? If so, why? If not, what did you try and how did it not work?

Comment: David. Well, nope I don't have evidence that the task switcher hook can be found.

Comment: Andlabs, I want to change the icon at the time of creation of the window, to not be a default microsoft icon that automatically loads. Why? For a game. What did I try? I was trying to create a .rc file and somehow get icon referenced in there, I also attempted to use LoadIcon with png.

Comment: Can you show your code for both attempts? And perhaps edit your question so that it doesn't sound like you're trying to do the former, because that's what David got the idea of.

Comment: And for the record, to clear up your confusion: none of the icons you named are separate. They're all the icon associated to the window class. The Taskbar and Alt-Tab switcher navigate windows, not applications or other things. (I don't know if this is still true for the  Windows 7 taskbar or not.)

Answer (score 0):

So, I found my own answer.

A) I could meddle with resource loading (which I did, and came out frustrated and unsuccessful at linking it to the LoadIcon function.

B) Second way: Use LoadImage and cast return value to HICON (hacky apparently, but it worked for all icons I was trying to change!!!!! So, problem solved hah.
Below is the pseudocode I used into my project.

```
   windowclass.hIcon = (HICON) LoadImage( // returns a HANDLE so we have to cast to HICON
   NULL,             // hInstance must be NULL when loading from a file
   "iconfile.ico",   // the icon file name
   IMAGE_ICON,       // specifies that the file is an icon
   0,                // width of the image (we'll specify default later on)
   0,                // height of the image
   LR_LOADFROMFILE|  // we want to load a file (as opposed to a resource)
   LR_DEFAULTSIZE|   // default metrics based on the type (IMAGE_ICON, 32x32)
   LR_SHARED         // let the system release the handle when it's no longer used
   );
```

So, if you want some other customization to above, I recommend going to MSDN definition of LoadImage and customize your parameters according to it.

Comment: It's not hacky so long as it actually does return an icon. [MSDN has an example that uses `LoadImage()`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: LoadIcon does not load it for me and to be honest I was too happy that it worked with loadImage to investigate further. the above website is what I used for reference before posting on here.